# Edit and Delete React Bootstrap table rows

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap table with columns to populate data. I have set up two action buttons, edit and delete. But I am not sure how to get those buttons to work. The code is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Card, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// datatable related plugins
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory, {
  PaginationProvider,
  PaginationListStandalone,
  SizePerPageDropdownStandalone,
} from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";

import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";

//Import Breadcrumb
import Breadcrumbs from "../../components/Common/Breadcrumb";
import "./datatables.scss";

// Table data
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Airi Satou",
    position: "Accountant",
    office: "Tokyo",
    age: "33",
    startdate: "2008/11/28",
    salary: "$162,700",
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Angelica Ramos",
    position: "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
    office: "London",
    age: "47",
    startdate: "2009/10/09",
    salary: "$1,200,000",
  },
];

class DatatableTables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breadcrumbItems: [
        { title: "Tables", link: "#" },
        { title: "Data Table", link: "#" },
      ],
      page: 1,
      sizePerPage: 10,
      productData: products,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        dataField: "id",
        text: "Id",
        sort: true,
      },
      {
        dataField: "name",
        text: "Name",
        sort: true,
      },
      {
        dataField: "position",
        text: "Position",
        sort: true,
      },
      {
        dataField: "office",
        text: "Office",
        sort: true,
      },
      {
        dataField: "age",
        text: "Age",
        sort: true,
      },
      {
        dataField: "startdate",
        text: "Start Date",
        sort: true,
      },
      {
        dataField: "salary",
        text: "Salary",
        sort: true,
      },
      {
        dataField: "menu",
        isDummyField: true,
        text: "Action",
        formatter: () => (
          <>
            <Link to="#" className="me-3 text-primary">
              <i className="mdi mdi-pencil font-size-18"></i>
            </Link>
            <Link to="#" className="text-danger">
              <i className="mdi mdi-trash-can font-size-18"></i>
            </Link>
          </>
        ),
      },
    ];

    const defaultSorted = [
      {
        dataField: "id",
        order: "asc",
      },
    ];

    const pageOptions = {
      sizePerPage: 10,
      totalSize: products.length, // replace later with size(customers),
      custom: true,
    };

    // Select All Button operation
    const selectRow = {
      mode: "checkbox",
    };

    const { SearchBar } = Search;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="page-content">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <Breadcrumbs
              title="Tables"
              breadcrumbItems={this.state.breadcrumbItems}
            />

            <Row>
              <Col className="col-12">
                <Card>
                  <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle className="h4">Default Datatable </CardTitle>

                    <PaginationProvider
                      pagination={paginationFactory(pageOptions)}
                      keyField="id"
                      columns={columns}
                      data={this.state.productData}
                    >
                      {({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => (
                        <ToolkitProvider
                          keyField="id"
                          columns={columns}
                          data={this.state.productData}
                          search
                        >
                          {(toolkitProps) => (
                            <React.Fragment>
                              <Row className="mb-2">
                                <Col md="4">
                                  <div className="search-box me-2 mb-2 d-inline-block">
                                    <div className="position-relative">
                                      <SearchBar
                                        {...toolkitProps.searchProps}
                                      />
                                      <i className="search-box chat-search-box" />
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </Col>
                              </Row>

                              <Row>
                                <Col xl="12">
                                  <div className="table-responsive">
                                    <BootstrapTable
                                      keyField={"id"}
                                      responsive
                                      bordered={false}
                                      striped={false}
                                      defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
                                      selectRow={selectRow}
                                      classes={
                                        "table align-middle table-nowrap"
                                      }
                                      headerWrapperClasses={"thead-light"}
                                      {...toolkitProps.baseProps}
                                      {...paginationTableProps}
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                </Col>
                              </Row>

                              <Row className="align-items-md-center mt-30">
                                <Col className="inner-custom-pagination d-flex">
                                  <div className="d-inline">
                                    <SizePerPageDropdownStandalone
                                      {...paginationProps}
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="text-md-right ms-auto">
                                    <PaginationListStandalone
                                      {...paginationProps}
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                </Col>
                              </Row>
                            </React.Fragment>
                          )}
                        </ToolkitProvider>
                      )}
                    </PaginationProvider>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default DatatableTables;
```

I need to make the edit and delete buttons functional. Delete should remove the row and edit should let me make changes. The table is from a template hence I can not figure out how to make these changes. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
const dealColumns = [
  {
    dataField: "id",
    text: "No.",
  },
  {
    dataField: "name",
    text: "First Name",
  },
// columns follow dataField and text structure
  {
    dataField: "remove",
    text: "Delete",
    formatter: (cellContent, row) => {
      return (
        <button
          className="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
          onClick={() => handleDelete(row.id, row.name)}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      );
    },
  },
];

const handleDelete = (rowId, name) => {
  console.log(rowId, name);
  //1 YourCellName
};
```

Similar question asked here:
[how to do delete function with a delete button in react bootstrap row event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842613/how-to-do-delete-function-with-a-delete-button-in-react-bootstrap-row-event)